# d3js area chart with json

Tags: json, d3.js, graph, charts

i'm using the d3js area chart examples with json [Chart Link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195).
the x and y axis are changing when we change the data feeding but no data shown in the graph.but i used a console log.so i saw the datas are already there in the x and y axis.could not figure out why does the data doesn't appear in the chart.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timeStamp); })
    .y0(height)
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.memberAverageLoadAverage); });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var json1=[{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437063744524,"memberAverageLoadAverage":51,"memberId":""},
{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437069850060,"memberAverageLoadAverage":5,"memberId":""},
{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437069910059,"memberAverageLoadAverage":6,"memberId":""},
{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437069970060,"memberAverageLoadAverage":15,"memberId":""},
{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437070030056,"memberAverageLoadAverage":20,"memberId":""}];

var data = json1;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timeStamp; }));
  y.domain([-2, d3.max(data, function(d) { console.info(d.memberAverageLoadAverage); return d.memberAverageLoadAverage; })]);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("memberAverageLoadAverage");


 Any help will be really appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.timeStamp); })
.y0(height)
.y(function(d) {return y(d.memberAverageLoadAverage); });
```

you should use `.y1(...)` instead of `.y(...)`.

I think that should do the trick!